# Python urllib request and urlopen time out for stats.nba.com

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib, urllib3

In my code I have the snippet below where x is the iterator for an external loop with season dates as the values and here MYPROPERUSERAGENT is a stand-in for my actual user agent:

```
for i in teamID:        
    url = 'https://stats.nba.com/stats/commonteamroster?Season=' + x.split('-')[0] +'&TeamID=16106127' + str(i)
    print(url)

    req = urllib.request.Request(
        url, 
        data=None, 
        headers={
            'User-Agent': 'MYPROPERUSERAGENT'
        }
    )

    f = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    print(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

This is directly from the docs but I'm still getting the error...

```
TimeoutError:[WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

An example url, the first one I'm using is [this](https://stats.nba.com/stats/commonteamroster?Season=1997&TeamID=1610612737). I've tried countless other ways of doing this too and usually end up just doing it in R because of how much of a hassle it is, but if someone could provide a solution it would be much appreciated.

```
https://stats.nba.com/stats/commonteamroster?Season=1997&TeamID=1610612737
```

Comment: what is x here in `x.split('-')`

Comment: x is '1997-98' because the commonroster params require the season's start year while the player stats I'm looking for later in the code require a range.